Does the center tap of a single phase distribution transformer get bonded to the grid neutral?

Here are the two wiring diagram.

Was this not covered by your previous question?

The grid doesn't have a neutral.

@Finbarr, well, In my previous question, I bonded the center tap to grid neutral but not sure if people noticed that. I asked AI's about this but some say yes, and some say no. That's why I asked again to make sure my confusion is addressed.

AFAIK, both delta and wye are used for distribution, so it's not correct to say the grid doesn't ever have neutral. It is usually (always?) grounded, albeit maybe through a protective device.

Certainly in the UK, there is no "grid neutral" - distribution over any significant distance is pure three phase.

Wonder how they get balanced loads without the neutral in the UK. But that's a topic for another day. I'm in the U.S. And i'm still learning about how North American Grid system is set up.

Neutral isn't run over long grid/distribution lines, it's provided to consumers from the local distribution transformer. (In NA local distribution can use single phase and neutral.) Unbalanced loads result in unbalanced phase currents.


Does the center tap of a single phase distribution transformer get bonded to the grid neutral.

No, it's bonded to an independent local ground, as shown in your upper diagram.

Thanks for the clarification!
